# Binary subtraction confusion $1001_2 - 0110_2$

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I wish to compute $1001_2 - 0110_2$, but I having trouble with how borrowing works. I know that to compute $0 - 1$, we must borrow. So $1001_2$ becomes $0011_2$. Now we have $0011_2 - 0110_2$, but for the second $ 0 - 1$ calculation, what do I do? There is nothing to borrow from.

Comment: $1001_2 $ becomes $201_2$ which isn't really a number but you can use it. You can then make $201_2$ to $121_2$

Comment: It works the same way as borrowing in base 10. What would you do if you should calculate 1000 - 10 in decimal?

Comment: @mathreadler in base $10$, to calculate $1000 - 10$. I would "borrow" from the $1$ to get the first zero to become a $10$. Then "borrow from the $10$ so it becomes $9$ to get the second zero to become a $10$. BUT, I don't see how this connects with binary subtraction. In my problem, borrowing from the $1$ so it becomes a $0$ makes the first zero become a $\boxed{1} \boxed{0}$. Borrowing from that becomes what? $0$?

Comment: what corresponds to 10 in decimal in the binary system? The smallest number that does not fit in a digit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your hint nor John's. For Johns, we are in base $2$ so i'm not really sure how to interpret that.

Comment: You don't add the borrow to the whole value. In base 10, you just make a 1 mark at the top or bottom when you subtract digit by digit. There really is very little difference, just that 10 isn't a decimal digit, and 2 isn't a binary digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than computing $1001_2 - 0110_2$, we can drop the last place and just focus on $100_2-011_2$ as this is the part that really involve borrowing.

\begin{align}100_2 -011_2&= (1 \times 2^2  + 0 \times 2 + 0 \times1) - (0 \times 2^2  + 1 \times 2 + 1 \times1) \\
&=  (1 \times 2^2  + \color{red}{(-1)} \times 2 + \color{blue}2 \times1) - (0 \times 2^2  + 1 \times 2 + 1 \times1)\\
&= (1 \times 2^2  + (-1) \times 2) - (0 \times 2^2  + 1 \times 2 )+ 1 \times1\\
&= ((1\color{red}{-1}) \times 2^2  + (\color{blue}2-1) \times 2) - (0 \times 2^2  + 1 \times 2 )+ 1 \times1\\
&=(0 \times 2^2  + 1 \times 2) - (0 \times 2^2  + 1 \times 2 )+ 1 \times1\\
&=1\end{align}

In general, if you need to borrow from your next neighbor in $d$-ary, subtract $1$ from it and add $d$ to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of subtracting that avoids the whole borrowing scenario. It's called [**Austrian subtraction**](http://web.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/courses/math_300/groupwork/altsub/aust.html).

Your subtraction problem would go like this

\begin{array}{ccccc}
     & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   - & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}

You start at the far right and look at 
$\; \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ \underline 0 \\ \text{?} \end{array}. \;$

> - You think 
>     $ 1 + \color{red} 0 = \color{red} 1$
> - You replace the ? with a  $1$.

\begin{array}{ccccc}
     & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   - & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
     &   &   &   & 1
\end{array}

Here is where things get different than you are used to. Next you look at 
$\; \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \underline 1 \\ \text{?} \end{array}.$

> - You think $1 + \color{red} 1 = 1\color{red} 0$
> - You replace the ? with a  $1$.
> - You *carry* the $1$ (in $1\color{red} 0$) as shown below

\begin{array}{ccccc}
     & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   - & 0 & 1^1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
     &   &   & 1 & 1
\end{array}

Next you look at 
$\; \begin{array}{l} 0 \\ \underline 1^1 \\ \text{?} \end{array}.$

> - You think $0 + 1 + 1 = 10$
> - You replace the ? with a  $0$.
> - You *carry* the $1$ as before.

\begin{array}{ccccc}
     & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   - & 0^1 & 1^1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
     &   & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}

> - You think $0 + 0 + 1 = 1$
> - You replace the ? with a  $0$.
> - You are done.

\begin{array}{ccccc}
     & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   - & 0^1 & 1^1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
     & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}